# How to replace specific characters in a string depending on a users guess

Tags: java, android

So I have two Strings, one named WORD and other LINES.
WORD is a string which user enters in an edit text.
LINES the same length of WORD but it is only consisted of '-' characters; for example if a WORD is "python" it would be "------" and so on.
I also have another editText in witch user enters a character.
If user enters a character which is contained in WORD, I want to replace all '-' in LINES where that character appears in WORD;
For example, if a WORD is "overflow" and user enters a 'o' I want LINES to be "o-----o-".

Comment: And what have you done so far? What is your approach?

Comment: for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
                        if (c+"" == letter) {
                            lines.replace("-", c + "");
                        }
                    }

Comment: it is complicated a little just know that i used c+"" to make it string so that i can compare it to letter which is already a string in my code